# Extracting part of a string in C

Tags: c

I want to extract part of a string within given limits in C language. I tried [strcpy()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) but it only extracts the first n characters from a string.
How can I do this?

Comment: You can do this by using a simple loop:

    `for(i=0 ,j = pos ; i<len ;j++ ,i++)
        s[i] = a[j]; `
   
Here pos is the position of the original string from where You want to copy. len is the number of character You want to copy that is the length. "s" is the temporary array where we save the copied value.

Comment: @RobinHalder: but don't forget to show the null termination, and do you need to check that the string is at least as long as the start position of the substring?

Comment: I am just giving him a view how can he implement that as the question is already answered :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Substring().  Here's a simple example:

```
string Str = "I only want to extract \"want\" from this string.";
string Str2 = Str.Substring(7, 4);
MessageBox.Show("String 1: " + Str +" - String 2: "+Str2);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Note that this question is tagged [tag:c] and not [tag:c#] or something similar.  What you've provided is not using standard C notations.  It might be C++, or some other language, but it isn't standard C.  I recommend deleting this answer. In the future, be careful to note the tags and the question content (it does say 'C' explicitly), and make sure that your answers fit the questions appropriately.